# AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'path'

Tags: python

I have a python script that I'm trying to execute but i'm not sure how it's meant to be executed. I don't program in Python so i'm unfamiliar with the language. [Here is the link to the script i'm trying to use.](https://pastebin.com/gndDBhqD)  Also, a [link the configuration it's using if you wish to see it.](https://pastebin.com/XTTpefTk) All it seems to do for what's relevant here, however, is set my path which I know is correct since other scripts (not linked here) work as expected with the configuration in that file.

Having a look at the script, I believe that the script is meant to be ran with the command line arguments: view, new, init. Thus, I ran the following in my terminal

```
$ lectures.py new
```

But I get the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lectures.py", line 156, in <module>
    lectures = Lectures(Path.cwd())
  File "/usr/bin/lectures.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.root = course.path
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'path'
```

Furthermore, my python version

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.1
```

EDIT:
[I wanted to add the reference as well for what I am trying to follow](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through your code, I think you might mean:

```
self.root = course
```

at that line.

`Path.cwd()` returns:

> ... the current working directory, that is, the directory from where you run the script.

that is, either a [`WindowsPath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.WindowsPath) or a [`PosixPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PosixPath) object. I believe it is `PosixPath` for you, and you can verify with:

```
import os
print(os.name)
# posix -> Linux
# nt -> Windows
```

This has no attribute `path`, and this is what your Interpreter tells you.